# Hiding elements from toolbar, implemented on a single activity, on various fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I'm trying to hide certain elements from my custom toolbar which I've deployed in the MainActivity (it is *the only activity* in my app).

Accordingly, BotomNavigation has been implemented which handles *3 fragments namely Home, Records and Statistics*.

The main *toolbar.xml* is composed as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_50dp"/>
```

As you can clearly see, it has

1. *TextView*, which dynamically displays and centers the name of the fragment the current user is on and
2. an *ImageView* which shows the authenticated user's image wherein the src is just a placeholder if the user doesn't have a profile picture.

Not everything works as expected using the following *MainActivity.java* :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTitle;
private String mUsername, mEmail;
private Uri mProfileImage;
private ImageView mProfileImageView;
private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;
private static final String TAG = "BottomNavigation";

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener;

public BottomNavigation() {

    navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    mTitle.setText("Home");
            mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profileImage).setVisible(false);
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_records:
                    mTitle.setText("Records");
            mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profileImage).setVisible(false);
                    fragment = new RecordsFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_stats:
                    mTitle.setText("Statistics");
                    fragment = new StatisticsFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mProfileImage).into(mProfileImageView);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_naviation);

    //replacing the default actionbar with custom toolbar
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mTitle = mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle);
    //disabling the output of the appname on the toolbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);


    //load the Home fragment by default

    loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
    mTitle.setText("Home");


    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            mProfileImage = currentUser.getPhotoUrl();
    mProfileImageView = mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

What I'm trying to implement is to **hide** the ImageView on the Home and Record fragment **but** Statistics.

To do this, I used the following in the respective case statements:

```
mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profileImage).setVisible(false);
```

However, for some reason the ImageView remains as is. What's interesting is:

**1.** that the place holder image continues to remain until and unless I move to Statistics fragment and fetch the image.

**2.** once fetched, the image remains continue to live in the toolbar even if move out from the Statistics, possibly, it is not getting hidden in the first place.

**3.** if I rotate into landscape, the fetched image gets erased, and I'm yet again presented with the placeholder.

I've also tried hiding the visibility by setting visibility gone on the ImageView itself, but to no avail.

```
mProfileImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

How can I actually go about in implementing the right logic, should I implement the toolbar in each and every fragment, which is certainly not a healthy practice and defeats the purpose of modular fragments?

Following are some screenshots in order for a better understanding:

[ImageView not getting hidden, shows placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMUMT.jpg)

[Is visible even in the Records fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP057.jpg)

[placeholder replaced with the user's image (fetched using FirebaseUI Auth)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awQI1.jpg)

[rotating into landscape switches back to Home fragment and placeholder is replaced with the fetched image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW19T.jpg)

[as soon as I switch into statistics, imageview is replaced with the intended image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62vdh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views inside toolbar is same like other views I tried changing visibility it works.

toolbar.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

  toolbar.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

my toolbar xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/appTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I was able to get it work, however some issues still persist, like ImageView persistent on the Home and Record fragment after fetching from Statistics, but of course it's another topic of discussion. Can you plese explain the difference between the following methods of making View.GONE: **1.** `toolbar.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.GONE)` **2.** `mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profileImage).setVisible(false);` **3.** `mProfileImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`? @pop

Comment: 1 and 3 are same there will be only difference in the way you are initialising the image. Regarding point 2 you added image as a view to the toolbar  but you are trying to find it from the menu ideally no such menu exists that's why this didn't work.